# NSOperation subclass isCancelled isFinished isConcurrent

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSOperation subclass.
I'm overriding main & ready.
It's not a concurrent op.

When I call [op cancel] the operation does not get removed from the queue.
I printed out [op isCancelled] [op isFinished] & [op isConcurrent]..

Operation is cancelled:1 Operation is finished:0 Operation is concurrent:0

What am I doing wrong?
Wouldn't the super class handle a cancelled op and change the key 'isFinished' for a non-concurrent op?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you override `ready`, you must also override `cancel`. What happens in the abstract class is that when cancel is called it sets the operation as ready so that the queue may call start, the start method checks for the canceled flag, then aborts the operation and sets isFinished=YES. Then the operation queue dealloc's the operation. You can't have one without the other.

Answer (score 2):

As a NSOperation subclass you are responsible to check [self isCancelled] periodically and quit the operation if it is YES. The operation queue can not (instantly) cancel operations that are already running.

Comment: Where would I check this? [op main] never gets called because isReady never returns YES. I'm trying to remove stale operations from the Queue based on an a timestamp. - (NSDate *)active;

Comment: NSOperationQueue automatically removes operations from the queue that have been cancelled and are not running yet. My answer explains how to cancel already running operations. You could cancel the operation in main depending on the timestamp.

Comment: @petersmith NSOPerationQueue auto removes operations when isFinished=YES. I assumed this would be handled by the parent class. The problem I see is that when I override isFinished inside my cancel method i see this.. _YourInstance went isFinished=YES without being started by the queue it is in_